# All variants method overriding

Tags: java, generics, overriding

Consider the scenario where we have two classes related by inheritance

```
class Parent {    
}

class Child extends Parent{   
}
```

1. If `Parent` declares a method with folowing signature:

   ```
   public String method(Number n) / /parent 1
   ```

   I know that in `Child` I can declare method with following
   signature(should be override)

   ```
   public String method(Number n) // chilld 1_1
   ```
2. But if `Parent` contains following signature:

   ```
   public <T extends Number> String method(T t) //parent2
   ```

   Child can override it by following signatures(2, separated):

   ```
   public String method(Number n)//chilld 2_1
   ```

   or

   ```
    public<T extends Number> String method(T t)// chilld 2_2
   ```

Are there other variants for overriding parent1 or parent2 ?

Comment: yes! In Child I can mark @Override

Comment: I suppose a child could take an input type that was less specific (Object) and thereby override/mask the parent call.  I.e. public String method(Object t) -- along with generic typed variants of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only looking for a variant then how the following -

```
public String method(Number n) throws RuntimeException
```

or,

```
public <T extends Number> String method(T n) throws RuntimeException
```

---

Also, the other that don't apply in case of `String`, because it's final, is that the overriding methods are allowed return a subtype of return type in the parent.

Comment: `public String method(Number n) throws RuntimeException, SomeOtherException`  etc.

Comment: In case of checked exceptions, it must be either the same exception or some subclass of the one in the parent, otherwise it's not allowed.

Comment: For instance if the method in parent throws `Exception`, the super class of all checked exceptions, then the sub class version can decide to throw only the `FileNotFoundException`, a check exception.